# Browser Mode options missing from IE11's F12 Developer Tools?

Tags: internet-explorer

Just downloaded the new IE11 development version. Just wondering where did the capability go to switch between IE modes such as older versions IE8 etc... It appears all they give us is a emulation bit which doesn't quite work to capture the true horror of IE8. If anyone else has found it would appreciate some direction. Thanks.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182636(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The right answer is to use virtual machines (like Virtual PC) to run older versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature was removed in IE11's version of the F12 tools. The stated reason is that developers were using this feature instead of doing proper testing, and the fidelity of the emulation was not very good.

**Update** At the 2013 DevReach conference in Sofia, an IE Evangelist showed that the Emulation feature was returned to the browser in a future (not yet released) update. It will probably appear around the time of IE11 General Availability (Oct 17, 2013).

Comment: Do you have a source for that?

Comment: I would like to see a source as well. I found the tool to be useful in many ways however it wasn't a true test as I have issues that crop up on a legit version of IE8 on an XP OS that will not show in the browser mode but it was a nice reference point. Thanks for the response Eric.

Comment: It is not completely removed: IE11 preview guide states that X-UA-Compatible header will kick in emulation mode (although it may be gone in future IEs)

Comment: The feature (Emulation via Developer Tools) WAS removed; X-UA-Compatible isn't a DevTools feature.